# CppCodeProvider, CompileAssemblyFromFile throws System.NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, codedom

The documentation for compiling C++/CLI using the frameworks CodeDom classes is somewhat lacking.

The background: I'm trying to write system tests for a piece of software I have written. The software generates code, and I want to test that the code can be compiled, and that the compiled code works as intended.

The code to be compiled and tested resides in a couple of source files. I want to compile the source file into an assembly, and then dynamically invoke the methods in it. I have experimented with doing the same C# sources, and I had a successful build and test in minutes. The C++ compiler always throws System.NotImplementedException.

Here's the code that blows up on me:

```
namespace CppCompilerTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                string strSourceDir = @"D:\Projects\CppCompilerTest\CppSource";

                using (var codeProvider = new CppCodeProvider7()) {
                    var options = new CompilerParameters { GenerateExecutable = false, GenerateInMemory = false };
                    options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(
                        options,
                        new[] {
                            Path.Combine(strSourceDir, "SourceFile1.cpp"),
                            Path.Combine(strSourceDir, "SourceFile2.cpp")                               
                        }
                    );
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Have I totally overlooked something? I'm wondering if maybe the cl.exe way is the faster route...